# why application restart in azur solve MQTT broker broken issue

Tags: azure, cloud, mqtt, iot

Work on Asp.net mvc project,  my project have MQTT with help of nuget package **m2mqtt**.Deploy the application in Azur cloud with out any broker like:Mosquitto just having the **m2mqtt.dll**.  to connect with broker  my project use bellow configuration. BrokerAddress, BrokerPort, BrokerAccessClientId my broker address is a **live ip** so my application  easily connect with my broker.It’s work perfectly but get problems sometimes my application m2mqtt become idle not communicate work with broker become broken. After given a restart on azur application it’s start working.

Need some explanation why m2mqtt become idle and why I need to restart application

Comment: Have you set a keepAlive value during connect?

Comment: @,thank for  your reply ,yes i set the KeepAlivePeriod in my connection method parameter as 3600

Comment: What's the time interval of your application sending packets to the broker? Have you tried monitoring the transmitting packets between your application and the broker?

Comment: @ Rita Han - MSFT ,thanks for your valuable information,is there any tool available to monitor packets between application and broker

Comment: @shamim You can use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/download.html).